# Has the legendary city of Dwarka been found under water?

Tags: india, architecture, mythology

There have been some reports in India that the legendary lost city of Dwarka has been found underwater:

- Unacknowledged.info (2014): [Dwarka. Mythical City Found Under Water?](http://www.unacknowledged.info/dwarka-mythical-city-found-water/)

> The explorations conducted in the Gulf of Cambay waters revealed sandstone walls, a grid of streets and some evidence of a sea port 70 feet under water. The ruins have been proclaimed the remains of the legendary lost city of Dwarka which, according to ancient Hindu texts, was the dwelling place of the deity known as Krishna.

- YouTube (2008): [Mysteries of Modern Asia](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6KkDMBhrAD4)

Has anything been found underwater? Is it Dwarka?

Comment: Relevant video that's interesting: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NVIsjx5X3QM

Comment: Part of the first article is blatant plagiarism of http://drs.nio.org/drs/bitstream/handle/2264/507/Migration_Diffusion_6_56.pdf;jsessionid=35F0ED491701ECC09B8C56A3D02CBEF4?sequence=1.

Comment: @HDE -- That's my point. It is hard to separate facts from Hindutva Nationalism. So I am looking for better sources of Information if any.

Comment: Related: http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/south_asia/1768109.stm It appears to be a different site, though.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're skeptical of this, other than the fact that you think that none of the numerous scientific studies on the ruins - and others - can be trusted. You may be right in that it can be hard to separate some facts from nationalism. But I think it's highly unlikely that all of the scientific research on the site is extraordinarily biased, as you seem to be claiming.

Comment: To the people who are unfamiliar with the history of India replace Dwarka with Atlantis and You can understand why this is important and not just another archaeological discovery.

Answer (score 2):

Dwarka is the headquarters of the Okhamandal taluka in Jamnagar District
and is situated in the extreme west coast of the Saurashtra peninsula on the Arabian Sea. Similar discoveries of stone anchors from Indian Ocean coastlines suggest that Dwarka anchors may be related to Indo-Arab trade between 8th century and 15th century AD.

Referring to research by National Institute Of Oceanography in [2005](http://www.currentscience.ac.in/Downloads/article_id_086_09_1256_1260_0.pdf), the anchors of Dwarka are not found to be associated with the Harappan or the Late Harappan Phase. The concentration of the stone blocks and structures are observed only at one location opposite to Gomati river mouth, and at no other locations in the area.  The exact period of these submerged structures are still a matter of debate since surrounding archaeological site study indicates that the submerged structure may not be as old as suggested earlier.

> Based on extensive, systematic underwater scanning of the area and specially absence of any pottery or other artefact even after airlift operations / underwater excavation at several places during last few years, present
>   exploration do not suggest that they belong to some habitation site, they rather appear to be the remains of a jetty.